# Форма не передает параметры

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Вот такая форма делает запрос `POST` запрос, но не передает параметры, почему ?

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="row grid-row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fromDate">Искать с </label>
                <div id="fromDate" class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="toDate">по </label>
                <div id="toDate" class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row grid-row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="urlHost">URL ресурса </label>
                <select id="urlHost" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="referer">Реферал: </label>
                <select id="referer" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row grid-row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Искать</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: потому что атрибуты `name` отсутствуют

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте свойство `name` DOM-элементам, предназначенным для пользовательского ввода данных.

```
<input name="???" ...
```